# Converting standard deviation for data on a logarithmic scale base 10 to stdev with base e

Tags: standard-deviation

I found a measure of standard deviation in the literature (mean=1.273, std=0.163, n=1642) computed for data on a logarithmic scale base 10. The original data is not available. Is there a way to convert this measure into a standard deviation on a logarithmic scale with base e?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any individual *positive* real number you can change from from its $\log_{10}$ to its $\log_{e}$ (or $\ln)$ by multiplying by
 $2.302585.$  In R (where `log10` is $\log_{10}$ and `log` is $\log_{e})$,

```
log10(10)       # log-base-10 of 10
[1] 1
log(10)         # log-base-e of 10
[1] 2.302585
```

In general, if you have a sample of values $X_i$ with standard deviation $S_X,$ then then standard deviation of $Y_i = aX_i + b,$ for $a>1,$ is $S_Y = aS_X.$

So putting the two ideas together, you can multiply the log-base-ten standard deviation by 2.302585 to get the the log-base-$e$ standard deviation. (Of course, all the the observations in the sample must
have positive values.)

**Example:** Suppose you have a random sample of size $n = 50$ from a population distributed $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=15),$ rounded to integers.  (I checked that the sample has all positive elements. A sample of size 50 from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=15)$ is very likely to have only positive elements; "Trust, but verify.")

```
 set.seed(1234)  # for a reproducible sample   
 v = round(rnorm(50, 100, 15))
 sum(v > 0)
 [1] 50                # checking that all 50 obs. are positive

 sd(v)
 [1] 13.30136          # SD of original sample
 sd(log10(v))
 [1] 0.06046202        # SD of log-base-10 of sample
 2.302585*sd(log10(v))
 [1] 0.139219          # multiply above to get log-base e of sample
 sd(log(v))
 [1] 0.139219          # SD of log-base-e of sample (directly)
```

Additional summary statistics:

```
 summary(v)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  65.00   85.00   92.00   93.18   99.50  136.00 

 summary(log10(v))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.813   1.929   1.964   1.965   1.998   2.134 

 summary(log(v))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  4.174   4.443   4.522   4.525   4.600   4.913
```

Exactly the same multiplication rule works for the maximum, mean, and quantiles of a sample of positive numbers. But ***not*** for the sample variance, which has squared units.

```
var(v); var(log10(v)); (2.302585)^2*var(log10(v)); var(log(v))
[1] 176.9261
[1] 0.003655656
[1] 0.01938192
[1] 0.01938192
```

*Note:* The sample in the literature must have had all positive values.
Of course, you can't take a log of 0 or of a negative number. In R, `NaN` ("Not A Number") results from an attempt to perform an illegal operation.

```
log(rnorm(10, 1, 1))
[1]        NaN -0.8724555        NaN        NaN -0.1771066
[6]  0.4466428  0.9737357 -1.4843634  0.9577818        NaN
Warning message:
In log(rnorm(10, 1, 1)) : NaNs produced
```

Comment: That makes sense. log10(x) * loge(10) = loge(x) which is where the constant loge(10)= 2.302585 comes from. Then Y= aX and Var(Y)= a^2 Var(X). Taking the square root then gives the formula SY = aSX. Is that the derivation you used? Then the standard deviation on the log scale with base e would be 2.302585*(0.163)= 0.375. All the original data were non-zero length measurements.

Comment: That's exactly right,